# Evaluate Derivative $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{10x-1.86x^2 - 8.14}{x - 1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring

Evaluate Derivative $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{10x-1.86x^2 - 8.14}{x - 1}$

I've already evaluated the limit using the $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$ definition of a limit, but now I'm curious as to how you would factor the numerator in $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{10x-1.86x^2 - 8.14}{x - 1}$ to get rid of the $x-1$ in the denominator.

A solution to the factoring problem I encountered was using Polynomial Long Division, but I'm curious for more ways to factor it.

Comment: is $t$ in the numerator supposed to be an $x$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Use the formula for the roots http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation. This gives the factorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of $-1.86x^2+10x-8.14=0$ are $x=1$ and $x=4.37634$.

So,the limit is equal to this one:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{-1.86(x-1)(x-4.37634)}{x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1} (-1.86(x-4.37634))$$

Comment: That's cool, I never really looked at it like that, yet it seems so obvious. Much appreciated, evinda.